# Strange behavior with git fetch

Tags: git, commit, rebase, git-checkout, git-fetch

I'm getting a big problem with GIT fetch...look this

```
$ git fetch
From server:project
   422b4cb..a04c062  master     -> origin/master

$ git show-ref
ba113be885e66a5306d1646cd3db0801170c04f8 refs/heads/alpha-release
a04c062261beeb4a951337ebb58745945cac3562 refs/heads/master
a04c062261beeb4a951337ebb58745945cac3562 refs/heads/test
a04c062261beeb4a951337ebb58745945cac3562 refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
ba113be885e66a5306d1646cd3db0801170c04f8 refs/remotes/origin/alpha-release
a04c062261beeb4a951337ebb58745945cac3562 refs/remotes/origin/master
```

And another `git fetch`:

```
$ git fetch
From server:project
 + a04c062...422b4cb HEAD       -> origin/HEAD  (forced update)

$ git show-ref
ba113be885e66a5306d1646cd3db0801170c04f8 refs/heads/alpha-release
a04c062261beeb4a951337ebb58745945cac3562 refs/heads/master
a04c062261beeb4a951337ebb58745945cac3562 refs/heads/test
422b4cbac3db2784c8f6e94ffd99c7afcda9122d refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
ba113be885e66a5306d1646cd3db0801170c04f8 refs/remotes/origin/alpha-release
422b4cbac3db2784c8f6e94ffd99c7afcda9122d refs/remotes/origin/master
```

And another one...

```
$ git fetch
From server:project
   422b4cb..a04c062  master     -> origin/master

$ git show-ref
ba113be885e66a5306d1646cd3db0801170c04f8 refs/heads/alpha-release
a04c062261beeb4a951337ebb58745945cac3562 refs/heads/master
a04c062261beeb4a951337ebb58745945cac3562 refs/heads/test
a04c062261beeb4a951337ebb58745945cac3562 refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
ba113be885e66a5306d1646cd3db0801170c04f8 refs/remotes/origin/alpha-release
a04c062261beeb4a951337ebb58745945cac3562 refs/remotes/origin/master
```

And another `git fetch`:

```
$ git fetch
From server:project
 + a04c062...422b4cb HEAD       -> origin/HEAD  (forced update)

$ git show-ref
ba113be885e66a5306d1646cd3db0801170c04f8 refs/heads/alpha-release
a04c062261beeb4a951337ebb58745945cac3562 refs/heads/master
a04c062261beeb4a951337ebb58745945cac3562 refs/heads/test
422b4cbac3db2784c8f6e94ffd99c7afcda9122d refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
ba113be885e66a5306d1646cd3db0801170c04f8 refs/remotes/origin/alpha-release
422b4cbac3db2784c8f6e94ffd99c7afcda9122d refs/remotes/origin/master
```

My `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` and `refs/remotes/origin/master` always force update to `422b4cb`...

What happened? `422b4cb`... is a old commit.

Answer (score 12):

Wow...after a big fight with GIT I fixed this issue just using:

```
git push origin :HEAD
```

Comment: solved the problem for me as well - "forced update" no longer happens on git pull or git fetch :)

Comment: This is actually the exact issue described in VonC's answer. This command will delete a branch called 'HEAD' from repo 'origin'.

Answer (score 4):

The only other instance where I saw that kind of behavior was in [this thread](http://www.mentby.com/Group/git/strange-happening-with-git-fetch.html):

> Looks like you have local branch '`HEAD`' (*not* the special ref `HEAD`) on remote side and that is messing it up.
>
> `ls-remote`'ing the repository shows '`refs/heads/HEAD`', right (there's also HEAD, that's the required special ref)?

Maybe commit `422b4cb` was when that branch called '`HEAD`' was introduced?

Note (7 years later): with [Git 2.16 (Q1 2018), you won't be able to create a branch named HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47581080/6309) anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what causes this problem, but you can fix it if you have shell access to the git repository:

```
$ [ ... log into shell on git server ...]
$ cd /path/to/repo.git
$ rm refs/heads/HEAD
```

It is the same as

```
$ git push origin :HEAD
```

in the working copy.  In my case we have the repo set up to deny branch deletion, so I had to log in and do it manually in this case.