# GIT: How to unambiguously reference current HEAD when having a branch called HEAD?

Tags: git, branch

Even though "HEAD" is definitely a poor choice for the name of a Git branch, it is still a valid branch name. If you happen to have branch named "HEAD", is there a way how to unambiguously refer to the actual `HEAD` symbolic reference?

The branch can be referenced as `refs/heads/HEAD`, but what about the `HEAD` itself?

Using just `HEAD` results in an `refname 'HEAD' is ambiguous` error anywhere where a `<commit>` is passed as an argument.

Comment: Horrible, horrible practice. But good question :). For the readers out there, if you're wondering whether you should named your branch HEAD, don't.

Comment: I think it will cost you less effort renaming this branch everywhere than solving this problem, only to get more trouble later on...

Comment: @MadaraUchiha With Git 2.16 (Q1 2018), you won't be able to name a branch 'HEAD'. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47581080/6309)

Answer (score 3):

According to [gitrevisions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html), if both `HEAD` and `refs/heads/HEAD` exist, the selected revision is `HEAD` (i.e., not the branch named `HEAD`).

This is in fact the correct answer for *most* situations, but `git checkout` prefers the branch-name to the revision, so `git checkout HEAD` resolves to the branch, rather than the current commit.

There are other commands that also choose the branch name, e.g., `git branch -f HEAD newrev` or `git branch -D HEAD` refers to the branch, but here there's no real room for ambiguity: `git branch` is *obviously* going to work on the branch.

Other handlers generally pass a branch name or a revision specifier to `git rev-parse` or `git rev-list`, and those behave as documented in [gitrevisions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).

Note that similar cases can occur with more realistic branch names.  Just yesterday I created a branch for dealing with a certain ethernet items, and named the branch `e1000` ... which looks like an abbreviated SHA-1.  A branch named `facade` suffers the same fate.

Answer (score 3):

The good news is, with Git 2.16 (Q1 2018), that issue won't come up easily anymore, since "`git branch`" and "`git checkout -b`" are now **forbidden from creating a branch whose name is "HEAD"**.

See [commit 662a4c8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/662a4c8a097248a3c08a671866ecf37743f3ca4d) (14 Nov 2017) by [Kaartic Sivaraam (`sivaraam`)](https://github.com/sivaraam).
See [commit a625b09](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a625b092cc59940521789fe8a3ff69c8d6b14eb2) (14 Nov 2017), and [commit bc1c9c0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bc1c9c0e674bdd293c29ae84365915848ed01d7a), [commit 8280c4c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8280c4c1ea59bc6d101c5616490627b63934318e) (13 Oct 2017) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 1616928](https://github.com/git/git/commit/16169285f1e63f6a3d9ec10e48f55d6825d3156b), 28 Nov 2017)</sup>

> ### `branch`: correctly reject `refs/heads/{-dash,HEAD}`

> [`strbuf_check_branch_ref()`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a625b092cc59940521789fe8a3ff69c8d6b14eb2/sha1_name.c#L1332) is the central place where many codepaths
> see if a proposed name is suitable for the name of a branch.
> It was designed to allow us to get stricter than the [`check_refname_format()`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/89ea799ffcc5c8a0547d3c9075eb979256ee95b8/refs.c#L117) check used for refnames in general, and we already use it to reject a branch whose name begins with a '`-`'.
> The function gets a `strbuf` and a string "`name`", and returns non-zero if the name is not appropriate as the name for a branch.
> When the name is good, it places the full refname for the branch with the proposed name in the `strbuf` before it returns.
>
> However, it turns out that one caller looks at what is in the `strbuf` even when the function returns an error.
> Make the function populate the `strbuf` even when it returns an error.
> That way, when "`-dash`" is given as name, "`refs/heads/-dash`" is placed in the `strbuf` when returning an error to `copy_or_rename_branch()`, which notices that the user is trying to recover with "`git branch -m -- -dash dash`" to
> rename "`-dash`" to "`dash`".
>
> While at it, use the same mechanism to also reject "`HEAD`" as a branch name.

---

Even if you tried to "cheat", and use [`git symbolic-ref`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-symbolic-ref) to point `HEAD` to a nonsensical ref (like '`HEAD`'!), that would not work with Git 2.38 (Q3 2022):
"[`git symbolic-ref symref non..sen..se`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8faaf690f7174a9b56438788308de4fa195893e2/Documentation/git-symbolic-ref.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-symbolic-ref))</sup> is now diagnosed as an error.

See [commit 04ede97](https://github.com/git/git/commit/04ede97211c132f4d71c96c61f5124cbb3ebdc77) (01 Aug 2022) by [Linus Torvalds (`torvalds`)](https://github.com/torvalds).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 8faaf69](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8faaf690f7174a9b56438788308de4fa195893e2), 12 Aug 2022)</sup>

> ### [`symbolic-ref`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/04ede97211c132f4d71c96c61f5124cbb3ebdc77): refuse to set syntactically invalid target
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Linus Torvalds</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> You can feed absolute garbage to symbolic-ref as a target like:
>
> ```
> git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/foo..bar
> ```
>
> While this doesn't technically break the repo entirely (our "is it a Git directory detector looks only for `refs/` at the start), we would never resolve such a ref, as the "`..`" is invalid within a refname.
>
> Let's flag these as invalid at creation time to help the caller realize that what they're asking for is bogus.
>
> A few notes:
>
> - We use `REFNAME_ALLOW_ONELEVEL` here, which lets:
>
>   ```
>   git update-ref refs/heads/foo FETCH_HEAD
>   ```
>
>   continue to work.
>   It's unclear whether anybody wants to do something
>   so odd, but it does work now, so this is erring on the conservative side.
> - We need to keep our HEAD-specific check for "does it start with refs/".
>   The `ALLOW_ONELEVEL` flag means we won't be enforcing that for other refs, but HEAD is special here because of the checks in `validate_headref()`.

You would get the error message:

```
Refusing to set 'HEAD' to invalid ref 'xxx'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use use `$(git rev-parse --quiet HEAD)` whenever you need the commit (or `$(git symbolic-ref HEAD)` if you want to know where HEAD "points to").

According to `git help rev-parse` `$GIT_DIR/<refname>` takes precedence over `refs/HEAD`, `refs/tags/HEAD`, `refs/heads/HEAD`, etc., etc. and `--quiet` will silence the "refname 'HEAD' is ambiguous" warning.

Everywhere that takes a *ref* you should be able to use `HEAD` to refer to the currently checked out "thing" and `refs/heads/HEAD` to refer to a branch called `HEAD`. If you find a place in Git which takes a *ref* (not a branch) and `HEAD` doesn't work then you should report it as a bug.